# Deciding whether LinkedList is a palidrome

Tags: java, list, algorithm, linked-list, palindrome

```
class ListNode {
    int data;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int data) { this.data = data; }
}

public static Boolean isListPalindrome(ListNode head) {

    if(head == null || head.next == null) {
        return true;
    } 

    ListNode n = head;
    ListNode fastPointer = head;
    ListNode reverse = reverseList(head);

    while(fastPointer.next != null || fastPointer != null) {
        if(n.data != reverse.data) {
            return false;
        }

        fastPointer = fastPointer.next.next;
        reverse = reverse.next;
        n = n.next;
    }

    return true;

}

public static ListNode reverseList(ListNode input) {

    ListNode current = input;
    ListNode next = input;
    ListNode prev = null;

    while(current != null) {

        next = current.next;
        current.next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;

    }

    return prev;

}
```

----Before reversing a list----

//ListNode n : 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5

----After reversing a list----

//ListNode n : 1

//ListNode reverse : 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1

Basically what I did here was to reverse the link and then compare the original list with the reverse one. However, when I compare the compiler returns "NullPointerException".

So I copied the code into IntelliJ, and tried to print the original and the reverse list. Turns out the original one has only 1 element in it, on the other hand, the reverse list contains 5 elements as the original list should also contain.

How do I solve this problem ??

Comment: `However, when I compare the compiler returns "NullPointerException".` Which line causes the error? That's where you need to start. Then you can use tips from [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to debug the problem.

Comment: If you need additional help, please provide a [mcve]. I cannot run your current code because it contains multiple compiler errors if I copy/paste it exactly as it is.

Comment: fastPointer = fastPointer.next.next;

Comment: That line has two possible ways to cause a NPE: either `fastPointer` is `null` or `fastPointer.next` is `null`. You need to narrow down which it is.

Comment: "Turns out the original one has only 1 element in it, on the other hand, the reverse list contains 5 elements as the original list should also contain. " So are you saying that you expect the original list to have 5 elements, but it only has 1? If that's the case, your problem is in other code you have not shown here. You will need to debug that code to see why your original list is not created correctly in the first place or if it is modified somewhere unexpectedly.

Comment: Did it occur to you that when you reverse the list, you end up setting the `next` pointer in `head` to `null`?

Comment: no, if I print the list before reversing a list then it fully contains 5 elements. I just edited the post

Comment: maybe it has to do something with referencing ??

Comment: Also, considering that this is a doubly-linked list, there's no need to reverse anything. Just find the last node. Then, compare head to last. If those are the same, then get the head.next node and last.prev nodes, and check. Keep going until 1) you get a mismatch; 2) the front pointer and back pointers are equal; 3) front.prev == back.next (i.e., the pointers crossed).

Comment: yeah but this is singly linked list :(

Comment: The problem is that when you reverse the list, that puts the `head` node at the end of the list. *You're modifying the list.*

Comment: is it from leetcode? Please, add link where you found the problem.

Comment: Oh yeah and how do I not modify the input list ??? Do you have a clue ??

Comment: No it is from firecode.io, basically the problem is that you have a singly linked list and you have to decide whether it is a palindrome or not.

Comment: *How do I not modify the input list?* One possibility is to add the `prev` links rather than reversing the list. Then you could use the method I described for a doubly-linked list. Another is to create another list, and reverse that. Or, you can do it recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of issues with your code.

Firstly, when you reverse the list you need to create a *new* list. Your current method reverses the original list.

```
public static ListNode reverseList(ListNode head)
{
    ListNode prev = null;       
    ListNode current = head;
    while (current != null)
    {
        ListNode node = new ListNode(current.data);         
        node.next = prev;
        prev = node;
        current = current.next;
    }    
    return prev;
}
```

Secondly, the test in your `isListPalindrome` method needs to be changed from

```
while(fastPointer.next != null || fastPointer != null)
```

to

```
while (fastPointer != null && fastPointer.next != null)
```

With these two changes your code works.

Test:

```
ListNode odd = create(1,2,3,2,1);
System.out.format("%s : %b%n", string(odd), isListPalindrome(odd));

ListNode even = create(1,2,3,3,2,1);
System.out.format("%s : %b%n", string(even), isListPalindrome(even));

ListNode non = create(1,2,3,4,5);
System.out.format("%s : %b%n", string(non), isListPalindrome(non));
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 2 1 : true
1 2 3 3 2 1 : true
1 2 3 4 5 : false
```

Utility methods:

```
static ListNode create(int... data)
{
    ListNode head, prev;
    head = prev = null;
    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        ListNode node = new ListNode(data[i]);
        if(head == null) head = node;
        else prev.next = node;
        prev = node;            
    }
    return head;
}

static String string(ListNode head)
{
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    ListNode node = head;
    while(node != null)
    {
        b.append(node.data);
        if(node.next != null) b.append(" ");
        node = node.next;
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is with a stack. Briefly:

```
current = head;
while (current != null)
    stack.push(current.data);
    current = current.next;

current = head;
rslt = true;
while (rslt == true && current != null)
    test = stack.pop();
    rslt = current.data == test;
}
// at this point, if rslt is true, then the list is a palindrome
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple solution;

```
boolean isListPalindrome(ListNode<Integer> l) {
    
    if(l == null || l.next == null)return true;
    
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> revlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    while(l != null){
        list.add(l.value);
        revlist.add(l.value);
        l = l.next;
    }
    
    Collections.reverse(revlist);
    
    return list.equals(revlist);

}
```